# In NodeJS/ExpressJS, how should one decide between using request params and query strings?

Tags: node.js, use-case, http-request

While I am starting to get a hold of NodeJS programming, I am a bit confused by when to use request params and how their practical use differs from using query strings.

In particular, I can do `localhost:8080/:param1` in the URL followed by `req.params` in the code or `localhost:8080/?param1=value` in the URL followed by `req.query` in the code, and get the same outcome - the value of *param1*. How should I decide when to use which? What is a good use case for either of these approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use

```
localhost:8080/param1value
```

when you are *referring to a resource,* as in

```
http://barnesandnoble.com/books/12345/how-to-win-friends
```

You use

```
localhost:8080?param1=value
```

when you are *supplying a parameter to a request,* as in

```
http://barnesandnoble.com/search?searchterm=friends
```